# Calculate proportional width of object (proportion: 1600x1080)

Tags: jquery, math, width

This is a simple jquery question: when my div `#wrapper` has a specific `height` (=browser height - 129px), i want to set the `width` of a inner div `#object` automatically too (cause I need a width for the object to read it out)

example of the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">

 <div id="object"> </div>

</div>
```

---

example (jquery):

```
$("#wrapper").css({height:(($(window).height())-129)+'px'});
$("#object").css({width: [ CALCULATION ], height: ($("#wrapper").height())+'px'})
```

---

the original proportion of the image is: `1600x1080`

here's the link to the attachment,  take a look at it (tinypic):
[http://www.imgplace.com/...age1.png](http://www.imgplace.com/viewimg143/460/26image1.png)

**additonal information:**

the heights `500px`, `600px` and `700px` you can see in the attachment are just examples, the heigth could also be `711px`, `623px`, `998px` etc.

My math skills aren't really good, would be great if someone could help me out

Kind Regards,

Hans :-)

Comment: Umm... this question is unreadable and seems to contain invalid jQuery code too. Can you please format/fix the question (you know there is a code formatting option available)

Comment: @Hans - Make sure to mark the answer that helped you as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the calculation you want is `Math.round($("#wrapper").height() * 1600 / 1080)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly the `jQuery.width` and `jQuery.height` functions instead of the `jQuery.css` function. Also, you could define the `div#object`'s height to 100% so you don't have to specifically set it...

```
$("#wrapper").height($(window).height()-129);
$("#object").width(Math.floor($("#wrapper").height() * 1600 / 1080))
            .height($("#wrapper").height());
```